# Solr doesn't search in entire indexed document

Tags: java, full-text-search, solr

I have a Java application that access a Solr Server to index and search document. The indexing is fine! But, when I tried to search for a word or expression that is placed after the page 20, I'm not seeing any results.

It seems like Solr is not indexing, but accessign the Solr web interface I'm able to see the entire document in the browser...

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm not able to go further!

Thanks for your reply! :D

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `maxFieldLenght` parameter in `solrconfig.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading your document using remote streaming then increase the default multipart limit.

In your solrconfig.xml file,

change multipartUploadLimitInKB to be as big as you need it.

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
```